# difference between responeJSON and $.parseJSON

Tags: jquery

Okay so when I usually work with JSON I collect data like this:

```
<?php 
    $some_array = array("success" => "The upload is successful", "failed" => "The upload has failed");
    echo  json_encode($some_array);
?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    success: function(data){
        var imported = $.parseJSON(data);
        ...
    }
</script>
```

but I I'm currently trying to figure a jquery plugin that uses responseJSON and I'm not sure how to use it:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
```

How does this work?

Comment: The code you posted is bits and parts of the whole and it is impossible to understand what you want. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Does PHP return correct Content-Type of application/json? Or is dataType: 'json' set?

Comment: `success: function(data){...` won't do anything useful outside of an object literal (as implied by the presence of the `<script>` tag. Please don't don't post invalid snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `console.log(responseJSON)` to get a look at the complete object.

**Edit**

The main difference here I would say is that `data` is a JSON string and accessing it as an object requires one to use `parseJSON` on it.

It seems `responseJSON` is already a JSON serialized object and as such you are able to immediately access it's properties without the need to use `parseJSON`.

Comment: Okay thanks going to read up on it more on the plugins website. Just thought I should throw it out here on stackoverflow to get more inputs.